# Scope of class variables in C#

Tags: c#, class, variables, scope

Why is this:

```
public myClass
{
   private int myVariable { get; set; }

   myClass.myVariable = 10;
}
```

better than this?

```
public myClass
{
    int myVariable = 10;
}
```

What is the difference?  Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Try compiling ;) Have fun with the error messages. This should answer the question.

Comment: The first defines a "Property" (get/set), the second a "Field".